# Vuefire with Chart on Vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vuefire, vuexfire

I am trying to sync my chart' array data with my firebase value. Chart getting arrays for label and data. I would like to bind this Chart data value to my firebase object. Here is normal chart creation with hard coded static values:

```
data()
{
return {appChart: {data: {labels: ["A"], series: [[3]]}},}
},
```

Now, I would like to bind this value (3) with my firebase object.. Normally I can use firebase object like this with no problem:

```
new Vue({
   data: () => ({ myObjA: null }),
   firebase: {
      myObjA: db.ref('myObjA'),
      asObject:true
   },
  })
```

But I cant bind and dynamic update this myObjA with Chart array series ‘a’ like;

```
data()
{
return {appChart: {data: {labels: ["A"], series: [[myObjA]]}},}
},
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `appChart` to be computed properties:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({ myObjA: null }),
  firebase: {
    myObjA: db.ref('myObjA'),
    asObject:true
  },
  computed: {
    appChart() {
      return {
        data: {
          labels: ["A"], 
          series: [[this.myObjA]]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, when I try static value in computed (like series:[[5]]) it is working good but when I try with my object from firebase (like series:[[this.myObjA]] )  it is not getting the data.. chart was empty

Comment: No. when I use this.myObjA in template directly, it is binding with firebase and working fine.. But when I use it on computed, it is not updated

Comment: Hi, when I print to console in computed method, first it printed empty like {} then after a second, it prints {“.value”:5,”.key”:”a”}  And my object in firebase: {“test”:{“a”:5}}

Comment: `series: []` needs an array, but as you console.log, `{“.value”:5,”.key”:”a”}` is an object.

Comment: But I am using like;  series: [[this.myObjA.a]] It should work right ?

Comment: I think I found the issue; I am using chartist and I change chartist to another chart library. Chart is now working good.